# PHP: Upload photos on fan page wall (for cronjob)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need upload photos to a fan page wall using php cronjob in this manner.

**http://i48.tinypic.com/kcgwo5.jpg**

I have token with permissions and tried several ways without success.

**test1.php:**

```
$page_access_token = 'accesstoken';
$page_id = 'idofmyfanpage';
$data['picture'] = 'urlofimage';
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $return;
```

But the result...

**http://i46.tinypic.com/5l5hfq.png**

This gray box...

I tried another way.

**test2.php:**

```
$page_access_token = 'accesstoken';
$page_id = 'idofmyfanpage';
$data['image'] = '@imagetoupload.jpg';
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/photos';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $return;
```

But upload the photo in my personal profile wall.

I also tried to upload in fan page timeline album.

http://graph.facebook.com/mypage/albums

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         },
         "name": "Timeline Photos",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&id=xxxxxxxxx&aid=xxxx",
         "cover_photo": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "count": 1,
         "type": "wall",
         "created_time": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "updated_time": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "can_upload": false
      },
      {
         "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         },
         "name": "Profile Pictures",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=xxxxxxxxxx&id=xxxxxxxxx&aid=xxxxxxx",
         "cover_photo": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "count": 1,
         "type": "profile",
         "created_time": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "updated_time": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "can_upload": false
      }
   ]
}
```

**test3.php**

```
$page_access_token = 'accesstoken';
$page_id = 'idofmyfanpage';
$data['image'] = '@imagetoupload.jpg';
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/idofalbum/photos';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $return;
```

Result:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#120) Invalid album id","type":"OAuthException","code":120}}
```

How could I?

PD: Sorry for my bad English.